# Run-time error 424 - Object required

Tags: vba, excel

I have this very simple VBA code, that I'm using to find certain pieces of text in columns and erase the entire row. But for some reason, everytime I run it gives me this error: Run-time error '424': Object required

Any clues?

```
Sub DeleteText()
   Dim c As Range
   Dim sArray(1 To 4) As String
   sArray(1) = "TEXT 1"
   sArray(2) = "TEXT 2"
   sArray(3) = "TEXT 3"
   sArray(4) = "TEXT 4"
   Dim SrchRng

   Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

   For i = 1 To 4

   Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find(What:=sArray(i), LookIn:=xlValues) ' <-- IT STOPS IN THIS LINE
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
     Loop While Not c Is Nothing
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure, it works just fine for me.

Comment: Strange behaviour: if I choose a text that doesn't exist in the table, it shows no errors. But as soon as I pick a text that DOES exist, the error comes back.

Comment: As you delete rows you change what `SrchRng` points to: eventually you may get to the point where you've deleted all of its cells, so it's no longer a valid range reference.  Once you reach that point, any reference to `SrchRange` will raise an error.

Comment: I see. Any thoughts? I'm pretty lost...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you delete rows you change what SrchRng points to: eventually you may get to the point where you've deleted all of its cells, so it's no longer a valid range reference. Once you reach that point, any reference to SrchRange will raise an error.

You can just collect the rows to delete as you loop, then delete them all at the end:

```
Sub DeleteText()

   Dim c As Range
   Dim sArray(1 To 4) As String, i As Long
   sArray(1) = "TEXT 1"
   sArray(2) = "TEXT 2"
   sArray(3) = "TEXT 3"
   sArray(4) = "TEXT 4"
   Dim SrchRng As Range, rngDelete As Range

   Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

   For i = 1 To 4

   Do
        'NOTE: use LookAt to ensure you're not making a partial match
        ' Unless you want that...
        Set c = SrchRng.Find(What:=sArray(i), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            c.Value = "" '<< so it's not found again
            'build up a range of cells to delete
            If rngDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDelete = c
            Else
                Set rngDelete = Application.Union(c, rngDelete)
            End If
        End If
     Loop While Not c Is Nothing
   Next i

   'delete any found rows
   If Not rngDelete Is Nothing Then rngDelete.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks! I just had to change the Range to Z65536 so it looked in all columns. Any suggestions on how to skip the first two rows (header)?

Comment: `Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A3", ActiveSheet.Range("Z65536").End(xlUp))`